# How to get node counts in random forests?

Tags: r, machine-learning, random-forest

Is there a way in random forests I can get the sum of the class counts for each of my nodes across all the trees in my random forests? The idea is to determine which levels of my predictors(which are all categorical) are most important in the prediction. I know the importance() function in R already does in determining the **importance of variables** but I want to determine which **levels of my predictor variables** are most important. For example, consider the following scenario:

- Response Variable: Click =1, Click 0
- Independent Variable: Type: Hippy, Yuppie, old person, young person

Is there any way I can understand what type of people are most likely to click on the ad(click =1) using random forests? Is this possible usng the randomForest package in R?  It is easy to look at one decision tree(ala CART) and see the node counts, but how do you do this when an ensemble of decision trees such as random forests?

```
#get variable importance
    rf1 <-randomForest(trainset[,5]~.,data=trainset[,-5], mtry=bestmtry, ntree=1000, 
         keep.forest=TRUE, importance=TRUE)
    importance(rf1)
    varImpPlot(rf1)
```

## CART: visualizing the nodes

```
# Classification Tree with rpart
library(rpart)

    # grow tree
    fit <- rpart(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start,
       method="class", data=kyphosis)

    # plot tree
    plot(fit, uniform=TRUE,
       main="Classification Tree for Kyphosis")
    text(fit, use.n=TRUE, all=TRUE, cex=.8)
```

Comment: When you say nodes do you mean terminal nodes? Also, you are asking for code and you have not provided any sample data. This means even more work for the person who will answer your question.

Comment: `getTree` function seems to be the only way. Then one needs to parse the matrix returned by this function.

Comment: There are several random-forest libraries with equivalent main functions and differing support functions.  Have you looked at what is in the other packages?